# Should C++ std::uniform_real_distribution<double> only generate positive numbers?

Tags: c++, random

I was trying to generate some random doubles in C++ (MSVC, though that isn't too important to me—I just didn't have another compiler to test) and I noticed that my quick program never generated negative numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 generator(clock());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>
        rand_dbl(std::numeric_limits<double>::min(),
                 std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

    std::cout << "Double Limits: (" << std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
              << "," << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << ")"
              << std::endl << std::endl;

    int total_neg = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        double d = rand_dbl(generator);
        if (d<0) total_neg++;
        std::cout << d << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl
              << "Total negative random double is: " << total_neg << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

No matter how many numbers I have it generate, it never generates a negative one. I understand why most of the numbers generated are in the 10<sup>307</sup> - 10<sup>308</sup> range (which isn't exactly what I wanted), but not why the numbers are always positive. I tried a few different generators (default, `mt19937`, `minstd_rand0`) without any difference in this aspect.

Can anyone describe why this is the case?

Comment: std::numeric_limits<double>::min() is still positive?

Comment: Doh! I printed it out and didn't even check that.

Comment: Yep. Use numeric_limits<t>::lowest() instead.

Comment: Why most of you numbers are in the range 10^307 - 10^308 ??\

Comment: @tobi303, probability. In this range, just more numbers.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm haha, sure. sometimes I am faster in writing than in thinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
```

Will return `DBL_MIN` which is the smalles value closest to 0 a double can hold.  If you want the largest negative value then you need to use

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()
```

Which will return `-DBL_MAX` which is the largest negative value a double can hold.

Answer (score 7):

You set it up that way with the limits that you provided.  `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` gives the smallest *positive* double, and you used that as the lower bound on the distribution.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min):

> For floating-point types with denormalization, min returns the minimum **positive** normalized value.

(emphasis mine)

So it's pretty normal you only get positive values.

Could you tell what is displayed by those lines?

```
std::cout << "Double Limits: (" << std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
          << "," << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << ")"
          << std::endl << std::endl;
```